# Is it safe to nest try/finally clauses like this?

Tags: java, nested, try-finally

As this is meant as a somewhat academic question regarding the behaviour of the try/finally clause, I tried to use an example that is very generic. Is there any danger in nesting a try/finally clause like this?

```
openDatabaseConnection();
try {
    // Methods unrelated to cursor
    // ...

    String cursor_id = openCursor();
    try {
        useCursor(cursor_id);
    } finally {
        closeCursor(cursor_id);
    }

    // Methods unrelated to cursor
    // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    genericLogError();
} finally {
    closeDatabaseConnection();
}
```

Specifically, I'm interested to know whether or not `closeCursor()` is guaranteed to be called before `closeDatabaseConnection()`. Is there reason nesting a finally clause like should be considered bad practice?

Comment: call both in same finally method

Comment: @divyabharathi: Please explain why you recommend this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed.

Say some exception occurred during `useCursor(cursor_id)`, now the *inner finally* block will be executed. (Since the exception happened in the inner `try` block). After this `genericLogError()` will be called (Since an exception occurred in the outer `try` that included the inner `try`. And only after it `closeDatabasConnection()` will be executed (the `finally` of the outer `try`). Here is a diagram that might explain it better:

**(Exception in the inner try → finally of the inner try )** → **this is considered an exception of the outer try** → **catch of the outer try** → **finally of the outer try.**

You can test it by printing from the blocks.

But why not to do it like this?

```
try {
  useCursor(cursor_id);
} catch(Exception e) {
  genericLogError();
} finally {
  closeCursor(cursor_id);
  closeDatabaseConnection();
}
```

Comment: Suppose I put  `closeCursor()` in the same **finally** block as `closeDatabaseConnection()`. If an exception occurs inside the **try**  block but prior to `openCursor()`, couldn't this result in `closeCursor()` being called without a valid `cursor_id`?

Comment: In this case it is better to separate them onto two different blocks. Then `closeCursor()` will not be called without a valid `id`.

Comment: I see. I am curious why so many Java developers encourage me to use one **finally** clause while nesting them achieves the same goal, and with such simplicity...

Comment: You can only have one *finally clause* for each *try-catch* statement. But if you have more *try-catch* you can have more *finally* of course.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, I am often urged to use one "big" try...finally block (as in your answer) instead of using nested try...finally blocks (as in my starting example).

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong about using nested `try-catch` blocks. It depends on what I want to achieve. In your example, I don't see anything wrong, perhaps you could make it more readable, but the logic itself is OK and doesn't suffer from anything.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this, assuming you need to nest the try-catch blocks like this in the first place. [Maroun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473648/43662) answer would be better for the example you provided. An example where the approach you suggested would be more suitable might be if you have lots of local variables involved in the "Cursor" clean-up:

```
openDatabaseConnection();
try {
    Cursor cursor = openCursor();
    CursorHelper helper = new CursorHelper(cursor);
    String cursor_id = cursor.getId();
    String something_else = cursor.getSomethingElse();
    try {
        useCursor(cursor_id, something_else, helper);
    } finally {
        closeCursor(cursor_id, something_else, helper);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    genericLogError();
} finally {
    closeDatabaseConnection();
}
```

The parent try block will catch the exception thrown by the nested one, but the nested `finally` block will be called first. This keeps the scope of the cursor variables encapsulated within the first `try/catch` block.

If you wanted to pull all this code into one `try/catch` block you would have to declare some of your variables outside the block, which can start to affect readability:

```
openDatabaseConnection();
CursorHelper helper = null;
String cursor_id = null;
String something_else = null;
try {
    Cursor cursor = openCursor();
    helper = new CursorHelper(cursor);
    cursor_id = cursor.getId();
    something_else = cursor.getSomethingElse();
    useCursor(cursor_id, something_else, helper);
} catch (Exception e) {
    genericLogError();
} finally {
    if (cursor_id != null) {
        closeCursor(cursor_id, something_else, helper);
    }
    closeDatabaseConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `closeCursor()` is guaranteed to be called before `closeDatabaseConnection()`, in this case.

You could put both calls in one `finally` block (move the call to `closeCursor()` to the same `finally` block where you call `closeDatabaseConnection()`), but that would require declaring the cursor in the outer scope, which may not be desirable. For example, you may want to put all the code working with the cursor into a separate method; in this case you would probably want to have the `finally` block which closes cursor in this new method.

In general, I don't think nesting of `finally` clauses should be considered a bad practise. One should rather consider the general readability of the code, things like number of lines in one method - perhaps it would be better to split your method into two, in this case there would be two `finally` blocks, one in each method. Or, if your code is simple and short enough to be in one method you could reorganize the code to have one `finally` block only.

Answer (score 1):

The execution of the finally clause is guaranteed when control leaves the try block. Here the control leaves the inner try block before the outer block, so the execution order is guaranteed.

There is no reason why this should be considered bad practice, apart from the fact that you are making a big method that could be split in two or more.

Answer (score 0):

Use try/chatch and then finally. 
And then your code is fine.
It is good coding practice to close cursor,connection always and here 
 you have to call `closeCursor(cursor_id)` before calling `closeDatabaseConnection()` which exactly you have done.
As finally block will always execute although some `Exception` occurs during execution of respective blocks, so here in your code cursor will close first and then database connection will close so this is perfect.

**Please find the modified code snippet for your reference:**

```
 openDatabaseConnection()
    try {
        // Methods unrelated to cursor
        // ...

        String cursor_id = openCursor();
        try {
            useCursor(cursor_id);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { //Added the catch block.
        genericLogError();
       } 
        finally {
            closeCursor(cursor_id);
        }

        // Methods unrelated to cursor
        // ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        genericLogError();
    } finally {
        closeDatabaseConnection();
    }
```

Or you can remove the inner try and can close both in the outer finally itself like:

```
//outer try block
try{
....
}catch(Exception e){
genericLogError();
}
finally {
         closeCursor(cursor_id);
        closeDatabaseConnection();
    }
```

This will also do.

Comment: Why do you suggest copying the **catch** block into the inner **try**? If I don't catch the exception there, won't it escape to the outer **try** anyway?

Comment: You have to add catch after try block. try block without catch block is not possible, as try block is used to catch exception only. Got my point? Or you can remove the inner try and can close both in the outer finally itself like:

//outer try block
try{
....
}catch(Exception e){
genericLogError();
}

Comment: Answer updated. Please check once. And let me know in case of any concern.

Comment: But **try** blocks aren't only used for catching exceptions, they are also used for clean-up code, as in my example. A **try...finally** construct with no catch clause is syntactically valid, compiles and executes just fine.

Comment: Yes. It will not give an error but this is not good coding practice Stephan.

Comment: Duplicating code is not a good coding practice. Many experienced users in [this thread](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131397/why-use-try-finally-without-a-catch-clause) seem to disagree that a catch clause must always be present.

Comment: So, its better to use the second approach Stephen.

Comment: You should not catch an exception if you can't do anything about it, like retrying the operation or communicating the problem to the user, at that level. Most often you want the exception to bubble up to the appropriate layer, which means try-finally without catch should be more common than try-catch.